# What is the difference between tf.keras.layers versus tf.layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

What is the difference between tf.keras.layers versus tf.layers?
E.g. both of them have Conv2d, do they provide different outputs?
 Is there any benefits if you mix them (something like a tf.keras.layers.Conv2d in one hidden layer and in the next, tf.layers.max_pooling2d)?

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer accurate for newer versions of TensorFlow. Consider accepting my answer instead.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since TensorFlow 1.12, `tf.layers` are merely wrappers around `tf.keras.layers`.

A few examples:

Convolutional `tf.layers` just inherit from the convolutional `tf.keras.layers`, see source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a6d8ffae097d0132989ae4688d224121ec6d8f35/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py#L217):

```
@tf_export('layers.Conv2D')
class Conv2D(keras_layers.Conv2D, base.Layer):
```

The same is true for all [core `tf.layers`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py), e.g.:

```
@tf_export('layers.Dense')
class Dense(keras_layers.Dense, base.Layer):
```

With the integration of Keras into TensorFlow, it would make little sense to maintain several different layer implementations. `tf.keras` is becoming the de-facto high-level API for TensorFlow, therefore `tf.layers` are now just wrappers around `tf.keras.layers`.

Comment: Does it mean that the both are same? When should I use which one?

Comment: @RAWNAK, Yes. We can use `tf.keras`.

Answer (score 11):

`tf.keras.layers.Conv2d` is a tensorflow-keras layer while `tf.layers.max_pooling2d` is a tensorflow 'native layer'

You cannot use a native layer directly within a Keras model, as it will be missing certain attributes required by the Keras API.

However, it is possible to use native layer if wrapped within a tensorflow-keras `Lambda` layer. A link to the documentation for this is below.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda

Comment: I see! But is there any significant difference between using one or the other?

Comment: No significant difference

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate, see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

`tf.layers` module is Tensorflow attempt at creating a Keras like API whereas `tf.keras.layers` is a compatibility wrapper. In fact, most of the implementation refers back to `tf.layers`, for example the `tf.keras.layers.Dense` inherits the [core implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/23c218785eac5bfe737eec4f8081fd0ef8e0684d/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/layers/core.py#L728):

```
@tf_export('keras.layers.Dense')
class Dense(tf_core_layers.Dense, Layer):
  # ...
```

Because the `tf.keras` compatibility module is checked into the Tensorflow repo separately, it might lack behind what Keras actually offers. I would use Keras directly or `tf.layers` but not necessarily mix them.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate: It's the other way around now, i.e. tf.layers just act as wrappers around tf.keras.layers. See my answer.