# Combine tf.keras.layers with Tensorflow low level API

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

Can i combine tf.keras.layers with low level tensorflow?

the code is not correct but i want to do something like that:create placeholders that later will be fed with data (in tf.Session()) and to feed that data to my model

```
X, Y = create_placeholders(n_x, n_y)

output = create_model('channels_last')(X)

cost = compute_cost(output, Y)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between tf.keras.layers versus tf.layers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089334/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-keras-layers-versus-tf-layers)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that link @Sharky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is the same as using `tf.layers.dense()`. Using `tf.keras.layers.Dense()` is actually a preferred way in newest tensorflow version `1.13` (`tf.layers.dense()` is deprectated). For example

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_train = np.array([[-1.551, -1.469], [1.022, 1.664]], dtype=np.float32)
y_train = np.array([1, 0], dtype=int)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])

with tf.name_scope('network'):
    layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, input_shape=(2, ))
    layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, input_shape=(2, ))
    fc1 = layer1(x)
    logits = layer2(fc1)

with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
    loss_fn = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)

with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_fn)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    loss_val = sess.run(loss_fn, feed_dict={x:x_train, y:y_train})
    _ = sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x:x_train, y:y_train})
```