# What is the difference between tensorflow.keras.layers and keras.layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have read a related question's answer about this on stackoverflow which explains the difference between *tensorflow.keras.layers* and *tensorflow.layers*, link:

[What is the difference between tf.keras.layers versus tf.layers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089334/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-keras-layers-versus-tf-layers)

But, it doesn't answer the difference between **tensorflow.keras.layers** and **keras.layers**, whereas I noticed I can import them also.

So, what is the difference between them?

Comment: My previous comment was not addressed to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras used to be able to support different backends (tensorflow, theano and CNTK). Since keras 2.3, there is no difference between `keras` and `tf.keras`.

An excerpt from the Readme of the [keras repository on github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras) :

> Multi-backend Keras and tf.keras
>
> Multi-backend Keras has been discontinued. At this time, we recommend that Keras users who use multi-backend Keras with the TensorFlow backend switch to tf.keras in TensorFlow 2.0.
>
> Keras 2.2.5 was the last release of Keras implementing the 2.2.* API. It was the last release to only support TensorFlow 1 (as well as Theano and CNTK).
>
> **The current release is Keras 2.4.0, which simply redirects to tf.keras.**